Drawing canvas shapes dynamically with setInterval in React
I'm making a simple game with HTML Canvas and React. The idea is that we have 2 heroes (big circules), which are moving on opposite sides of the field and throwing spells (small circules) to each other. Also we have 2 inputs for each hero to change their movement and casting speed. By now everything seems to be ok with the movement speed, but the casting speed actually changes not after the range input update, but only after putting the coursor on the canvas field.
Here is my code:
(Yes, the coordinates calculation finctionality should be moved to a separate file. I'm going to do it later)
App.js
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import data from "./components/data";
import { collisionBorder } from "./components/collisionBorder";
import { addSpell } from "./components/Spell/SpellCast";
import { HeroMove } from "./components/Hero/HeroMove";
import { useInterval } from "./hooks/useInterval";

const { hero1, hero2, spell } = data;

function App() {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

  const [mouseCoordinates, setMouseCoordinates] = useState([]);
  const [hero1Coordinates, setHero1Coordinates] = useState([]);
  const [hero2Coordinates, setHero2Coordinates] = useState([]);

  const handleCanvasOver = (event, hero1, hero2) => {
    function getRelativeCoordinates(e, el) {
      const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
      const x = e.clientX - rect.left;
      const y = e.clientY - rect.top;
      return { x, y };
    }

    const currentMouseCoord = getRelativeCoordinates(event, event.target);
    setMouseCoordinates([...mouseCoordinates, currentMouseCoord]);

    const currentHero1Coord = { x: hero1.x, y: hero1.y, rad: hero1.rad };
    setHero1Coordinates([...hero1Coordinates, currentHero1Coord]);

    const currentHero2Coord = { x: hero2.x, y: hero2.y, rad: hero2.rad };
    setHero2Coordinates([...hero2Coordinates, currentHero2Coord]);

    function isIntersect(point, hero) {
      return (
        Math.sqrt((point.x - hero.x) ** 2 + (point.y - hero.y) ** 2) < hero.rad
      );
    }

    if (isIntersect(currentMouseCoord, hero1)) {
      hero1.dy *= -1;
    } else if (isIntersect(currentMouseCoord, hero2)) {
      hero2.dy *= -1;
    }
  };

  function rangeInputHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (event.target.id === "hero1_move-speed_control") {
      hero1.moveSpeed = event.target.value;
    }
    if (event.target.id === "hero2_move-speed_control") {
      hero2.moveSpeed = event.target.value;
    }

    if (event.target.id === "hero1_cast-speed_control") {
      hero1.castSpeed = event.target.value * 1000;
    }
    if (event.target.id === "hero2_cast-speed_control") {
      hero1.castSpeed = event.target.value * 1000;
    }
  }

// adding new spell to pool for each hero with an interval
 useInterval(() => {
    addSpell(hero1, spell);
  }, hero1.castSpeed);
  useInterval(() => {
    addSpell(hero2, spell);
  }, hero2.castSpeed);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    const render = () => {
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      HeroMove(context, hero1);
      HeroMove(context, hero2);

      // casting spells from pool

      hero1.spellPool.forEach((spell) => {
        spell.cast(context);
      });
      hero2.spellPool.forEach((spell) => {
        spell.cast(context);
      });
      collisionBorder(canvas, hero1, hero2);
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
    };

    render();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="game">
      <div className="game-header">
        <div id="hero1-score" className="game-score">
          <span className="score-count">0</span>
        </div>
        <button>Refresh game</button>
        <div id="hero2-score" className="game-score">
          <span className="score-count">0</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="game-body">
        <div id="hero1-settings" className="hero-settings">
          <div className="hero1_cast-speed_wrapper input-wrapper">
            <input
              id="hero1_cast-speed_control"
              name="hero1_cast-speed_control"
              type="range"
              min="1"
              max="5"
              onChange={(event) => rangeInputHandler(event)}
            ></input>
            <label htmlFor="hero1_cast-speed_control">Cast speed</label>
          </div>
          <div className="hero1_move-speed_wrapper input-wrapper">
            <input
              id="hero1_move-speed_control"
              name="hero1_move-speed_control"
              type="range"
              min="1"
              max="5"
              onChange={(event) => rangeInputHandler(event)}
            ></input>
            <label htmlFor="hero1_move-speed_control">Move speed</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="canvas-wrapper">
          <canvas
            id="game-canvas"
            ref={canvasRef}
            onMouseMove={(event) => handleCanvasOver(event, hero1, hero2)}
            width="620"
            height="400"
          ></canvas>
        </div>
        <div id="hero2-settings" className="hero-settings">
          <div className="hero2_move-speed_wrapper input-wrapper">
            <input
              id="hero2_move-speed_control"
              name="hero2_move-speed_control"
              type="range"
              min="1"
              max="5"
              onChange={(event) => rangeInputHandler(event)}
            ></input>
            <label htmlFor="hero2_move-speed_control">Move speed</label>
          </div>
          <div className="hero2_cast-speed_wrapper input-wrapper">
            <input
              id="hero2_cast-speed_control"
              name="hero2_cast-speed_control"
              type="range"
              min="1"
              max="5"
              onChange={(event) => rangeInputHandler(event)}
            ></input>
            <label htmlFor="hero2_cast-speed_control">Cast speed</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


SpellCast.js
export function addSpell(hero, spell) {
  hero.spellPool = [];
  hero.spellPool.push(
    new Spell(
      hero.x,
      hero.y,
      spell.dx,
      spell.dy,
      spell.rad,
      hero.spellColor,
      hero.id
    )
  );
}

export class Spell {
  constructor(x, y, dx, dy, rad, color, dir) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.dx = dx;
    this.dy = dy;
    this.rad = rad;
    this.color = color;
    this.dir = dir;
  }
  cast(context) {
    context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = this.color;
    context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.rad, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fill();
    if (this.dir === 1) {
      this.x += this.dx;
    } else {
      this.x -= this.dx;
    }
  }
}


Project's current full code
As i see it, defining the hero's castSpeed property as a value for setInterval delay should be placed inside useEffect to work correctly. I've tried different solutions, but none of them worked as expected. In'm not very experienced in React and i'm really stuck to make it work. If someone could suggest a working solution, that would be great.
Thank you!

There is a fairly critical flaw in your code that appears throughout in that you are mutating objects that are outside of reacts scope (hero and hero2), which are required in render. This is the fundamental cause and a critical design flaw that needs to be addressed. All of those objects need to live in react state and be mutated only in immutable state transitions via their setters. You would likely benefit from going through the react docs as a whole. Specifically see https://react.dev/learn/keeping-components-pure#side-effects-unintended-consequences and general pure component guidance.

Theres likely many other bugs either now or in future since the approach fundamentally breaks core requirements about how data is managed in react. However to relate back to your issue, the reason it doesn't update is because when you ("illegally") mutate castSpeed , react has no idea that happened since that isn't being represented as react state. No re-render will occur and therefore the useInterval will continue referencing stale values. Eventually, the change is affected incidentally when some other action (canvas mouse over) occurs where you do trigger a rerender via state setters.
